# __list_add Vs list_add in linux linked list

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, doubly-linked-list

I struggle to understand how `__list_add` Vs `list_add`  works? I did read some answers here but could not understand well. I have formulated my question in the attached file... Would please be so kind to have a look and advise me ?

Thank you[image]

Comment: Note, that multiple questions in the question post are discouraged on Stack Overflow. And the question-on-the-image is discouraged too.

Comment: `list_add` fails because it does not deal with the case of a list with 0 or 1 element. The `__list_add` helper function can only be called with lists of at least two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating the `__list_add` inline function into the body of `list_add` produces this equivalent:

```
static inline list_add(struct list_head *head, struct list_head *new)
{
    head->next->prev = new;
    new->next = head->next;
    new->prev = head;
    head->next = new;
}
```

This will insert the `new` entry between `head` and `head->next`. Normally, `head` points to the control node of the doubly linked list and `new` is the entry to be added to front of the doubly linked list.

Original state:

```
[oldheadprev]   [head]                       [oldheadnext]
    next ------> next -------------------------> next
    prev <------ prev <------------------------- prev

                                  [new]
                                  next
                                  prev
```

After `head->next->prev = new;`:

```
[oldheadprev]   [head]                       [oldheadnext]
    next ------> next -------------------------> next
    prev <------ prev                         ,- prev
                                             /
                                  [new]     /
                                  next     /
                                  prev <--'
```

After `new->next = head->next;`:

```
[oldheadprev]   [head]                       [oldheadnext]
    next ------> next --------------------> ,--> next
    prev <------ prev                      /  ,- prev
                                          /  /
                                  [new]  /  /
                                  next -'  /
                                  prev <--'
```

After `new->prev = head;`:

```
[oldheadprev]   [head]                       [oldheadnext]
    next ------> next --------------------> ,--> next
    prev <------ prev <-,                  /  ,- prev
                         \                /  /
                          \       [new]  /  /
                           \      next -'  /
                            `---- prev <--'
```

After `head->next = new;`:

```
[oldheadprev]   [head]                       [oldheadnext]
    next ------> next ----,                 ,--> next
    prev <------ prev <-,  \               /  ,- prev
                         \  \             /  /
                          \  \    [new]  /  /
                           \  `-> next -'  /
                            `---- prev <--'
```

The code works even if the list is empty. In an empty list, the `next` and `prev` pointers of the control node (`head`) point to itself: `head->next = head; head->prev = head;`.

Original empty list state:

```
          [head]              [new]
     ,---> next -----,        next
     |  ,- prev <-,  |        prev
     |  `---------'  |
     `---------------'
```

After `head->next->prev = new;`:

```
          [head]              [new]
     ,---> next -----,        next
     |  ,- prev      |        prev <-,
     |  `------------|---------------'
     `---------------'
```

After `new->next = head->next;`:

```
          [head]              [new]
 ,-> ,---> next -----,        next -----,
 |   |  ,- prev      |        prev <-,  |
 |   |  `------------|---------------'  |
 |   `---------------'                  |
 `--------------------------------------'
```

After `new->prev = head;`:

```
          [head]              [new]
 ,-> ,---> next -----,        next -----,
 |   |  ,- prev <----|------- prev <-,  |
 |   |  `------------|---------------'  |
 |   `---------------'                  |
 `--------------------------------------'
```

After `head->next = new;`:

```
          [head]              [new]
 ,-------> next ------------> next -----,
 |      ,- prev <------------ prev <-,  |
 |      `----------------------------'  |
 |                                      |
 `--------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Ian Abbott thank you you so much ... I struggled so much to understand it well. You are brilliant!

Comment: Hi, how do you generate these asci pictures?

Comment: @陳力 Using Vim and a lot of patience!